# Same size of axes if one of them has set_aspectratio to "equal"

Tags: python, matplotlib, aspect-ratio

Imagine the following simple situation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

ax1.plot(np.arange(10))
ax1.set_aspect("equal")

ax2.plot(np.arange(10), np.arange(0, 1, .1))

plt.show()
```

[image: Example Figure]

What would be the best/easiest solution so that ax2 has the same width/height as ax1, no matter what the aspectratio of ax2 is?

Comment: The question implies that you want ax1 to have this square shape, and you want ax2 to match it. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific case, you can set the aspect ratio of `ax2` to 10, such as bellow:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

ax1.plot(np.arange(10))
ax1.set_aspect("equal")

ax2.plot(np.arange(10), np.arange(0, 1, .1))

# Determining the ranges
x1,x2 = ax2.get_xlim()
y1,y2 = ax2.get_ylim()
xRange = x2-x1
yRange = y2-y1

ax2.set_aspect(xRange/yRange)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Even though it is not a general solution, it helped me to solve my problem as well.

Comment: Let me know if the last changes suits you. Cheers

Comment: I came up with the same solution :) However, it doesn't work for all cases, e.g. if ax2.plot([3, 4], [24, 32]). Anyhow, I can leave with the solution you posted :) Thanks!

Comment: You were absolutely right, so for the sake of correctness I made another change. I believe you might have got a similar idea.